# Freestyle not working in Blender 2.78c

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, freestyle

I understand that this type of question has been asked at least 50x, but please read me out.

This is as simple as it gets: Freestyle is not rendering in the final render. It simply does not work. Yes, I know this question already exists, but despite checking to make sure *no* settings were touched, despite trying this with a simple cube, it does not work. The "Include" option is running, not "Exclude".

[image]

I understand this is really ridiculous, but may I ask just what I am missing? I have previously used 2.79 builds, but I am not sure if that affects 2.78c, if that means anything. Please note that I am currently attempting this with Cycles, in case this ruins the whole thing.

Comment: Here are the current settings: 
http://imgur.com/41k8LWM
http://imgur.com/4tV43dF

What do you mean, enabled in Rendering? I turned on the checkmark, if that is what you mean.

...If I sound like an idiot, I would completely understand, I just feel so blind, right now.

Comment: http://imgur.com/UNm6mGe No modifiers until this: http://imgur.com/RrTm6Ei How do I find out about the mesh being used for lines? I tried it with the cube, nothing worked, no settings changed. http://imgur.com/mJelp21

Comment: If you tried with default cube then the mesh is suitable for freestyle. As I get it seems to not work if default file is opened and rendered default cube (pressing F12 to render) with default freestyle settings. In that case this might be a bug in this Blender version, check if there are newer versions available and try them.

Comment: I have tried today's Blender build. Nothing. It did not work. I have no idea if this is related to my computer or it's settings, or even that I used 2.8 builds, causing problems in the process...

Comment: Can you [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) the file? The last step would be to file a bug report at [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1) as you tried the latest build and didn't get freestyle.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3517/ Here it is. ...Oh, and I got a notice telling me to avoid extended discussions in  comments. Shall we move this to a chat? ...You know, before I get punished in some way?

Comment: I don't think it's needed, I'm not really going to go any further (neither do I think you will be that punished). The freestyle from the file you uploaded renders for me, the only thing I changed was enabling freestyle in Render rollout > Freestyle tab (was unchecked for some reason). It's likely not a problem as without it you won't have freestyle line styles available. So it's likely a bug in recent Blender version somehow (I use 2.78a now).

Comment: Alright, I will add this as an answer. Thanks.

For some strange reason, even though I had it checked, proven in the Imgur screenshots, it as unchecked when I reopened the file, which I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a bug, though it likely *could* be, as I had recently discussed with user "Mr Zak". The idea is to save the file, even though "Freestyle" is checked in the Render tab, then reopen the file. You may notice "Freestyle", in the Render tab, is now *unchecked*. ...Strange, huh? Check Freestyle again, then render it. Confused? So am I. However, this is the current working solution, and while Mr Zak pointed out he was using 2.78a, I am currently using 2.78c, at the time of this post.

Edit 6 days 55 minutes later:
I feel like an idiot, but I needed a minute in Blender's Discord to find out the fatal mistake: ...Pressing the wrong render button.
...You read me correctly, I was pressing the wrong render button, this *entire time*!

[image: Wrong Render Button]

This is the button I have been using to render, this entire time. As the locals in Blender's Discord have informed me, a detail I have been overlooking for too long, much less to begin with, this renders OpenGL. That means you will be given a render of exactly what you see in the viewport, completely different from when you look in rendered view.

[image: Correct Render buttons]

The buttons circles in this picture here, are the buttons you *should* be using for *final* renders, as opposed to OpenGL giving simply previews. That means that the button circles in the top-left section and the button circles on the right-hand side act as final render buttons, the equivalent of pressing F12 on your connected keyboard. Meanwhile, pressing the button underlined in this picture, and pressing the button depicted in the previous picture, will render only what you see in your viewport. If you want to see Freestyle lines, as I have been seeking, you want to use F12 render.

In case anyone is wondering, I have been asked if I had messed with the keybinds. I am not sure if this has *anything* relevant to do with it, but no, I did not mess with the keybinds. I have simply been blindly using the OpenGL render instead of F12's render, believing to have achieved the same results. I hope this proves educational and informational to *anyone* else who would ever make the same mistake *I* have made.